# Django migration not working with postgresql?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I have models :

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    keyword_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

But when I create migrate this model it give error

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "main_Keyword" does not
>   exist

I have try many ways but it's not working.Firstly this project i'm create on local using sqlite database but when I migrate database to postgresql then it give this error. what is my mistake?

EDIT :

> Request Method:   GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/main/keyword/ Django Version:   1.9.6
>   Exception Type:   ProgrammingError Exception Value:    column
>   main_keyword.keyword_category_id does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...ain_keyword"."id", "main_keyword"."keyword_name", "main_keyw...
>                                                                ^

Comment: Post the full stacktrace. This error usually means that you are trying to use the Keyword class (for example by querying it) *before* the migration can actually take place.

Comment: Try defining the `Category` model above the `Keyword` model since `Keyword` depends on `Category`.

Comment: In my models.py file Category define above the Keyword.But not working.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, from the error message, the models seem to be registered in the `admin.py`.

Delete the code in `admin.py` and try the migration again.